# When does PassThrough stream.write throws ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED or just do no-op after destroyed?

Tags: node.js, stream

My code:

```
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough
const strm = new PassThrough()
strm.destroy()
strm.write('abcd')  // no-op
```

Last `strm.write` does nothing and return `false` in node 14.7 (latest), and throws `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED`in node 12.18.3 (LTS).

In [documentation of LTS node](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/stream.html#stream_writable_destroy_error),

> Destroy the stream. Optionally emit an `'error'` event, and emit a
> `'close'` event (unless `emitClose` is set to `false`). After this call, the
> writable stream has ended and subsequent calls to `write()` or `end()`
> will result in an `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` error. This is a destructive
> and immediate way to destroy a stream. Previous calls to `write()` may
> not have drained, and may trigger an `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` error. Use
> `end()` instead of destroy if data should flush before close, or wait
> for the `'drain'` event before destroying the stream.

So it clearly says that it will throw `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED`.

However, in [documentation of latest node](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_destroy_error), the following sentence is added.

> Once `destroy()` has been called any further calls will be a noop and no
> further errors except from `_destroy` may be emitted as `'error'`.

While the previous documentation about `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` is not invalidated.

What is the exact condition for the `write` method of a destroyed `PassThrough` stream to throw `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED` or to do no-op in node 14? Please provide proof-of-concept code throwing `ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED`.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? With node 12 I get `Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroye`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon In latest 14.7 `strm.write` is just no-op.